# Flutter Navigation after receiving Push Notification with FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

The structure of my app is like the following:

RootPage -> Authenticated 
            ? LoadingScreen (after current user is loaded the user is navigated to HomeScreen)
            : SignUpPage

In HomeScreen there is a PageView with 5 children and I want to navigate to page index 3 after opening a push notification.

I call the fcm listener in HomeScreen init

First I tried it without using a delay but that does not work at all.

```
onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false).then((_) => pageController.jumpToPage(3));
      }
```

Then I used a delay like so with a print statement to test it and it worked!

```
onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000))
              .then((_) => print("Jumped to page index 3"));
      }
```

So I tried it with jumping to page index 3

```
onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000))
              .then((_) => pageController.jumpToPage(3));
      }
```

With this code the navigation to HomeScreen worked but not the jump to index 3 after resuming the app.
I don't know why. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Have you debugged? Did onResume get called?

Comment: Yes ```Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);```works as expected but not ```Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000))
              .then((_) => pageController.jumpToPage(3));```